# Como faço para resolver um problema de potenciação de maneira alternativa?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso de ajuda referente a resolução de um problema de potenciação de maneira alternativa.

O objetivo é mostrar o resultado da potenciação e o número de caracteres (ou números) que aparecem no resultado. O código que irei colocar a seguir eu consegui colocar para funcionar através de algumas conversões de caractere para inteiro e vice-versa.

```
base = input('Base: ')
expoente = input('Expoente: ')
potencia = int(base) ** int(expoente)
print('Potência: %d' %potencia)
digito = len(str(potencia))
print('Digitos: %d' %digito)
```

Porém, quando fiz uma chamada não se especificamente para a biblioteca matemática, acabei não tendo sucesso na resolução do problema. O resultado da variável `potencia` sai correto, mas o resultado da variável `digito` aparece de maneira errônea.

O código que não funcionou é semelhante ao anterior, ele tem apenas as alterações alterações abaixo comparado ao de cima.

```
# potencia = int(base) ** int(expoente) (Colocado como comentário para visualização)
import math
potencia = math.pow(int(base),int(expoente))
```

Não sei se o resultado da variável `potência` é um número inteiro após a chamada da biblioteca matemática, ou uma variável do tipo caractere, inclusive por isso estou tentando realizar a conversão do suposto número inteiro para caractere através do uso da função `len()`.

Como poderia resolver o problema de acordo com o segundo código?

Comment: O retorno de `math.pow` é `float`. Não consigo entender qual é o problema. Eu já li 5 vezes a sua pergunta. Por favor, tente ser mais sucinto e específico. Tente responder o seguinte: 1. O que você está tentando fazer? 2. Qual é o resultado esperado? 3. Qual o resultado atual (problemático)?

Comment: Ok. Estou tentando que apareça o número correto da variável dígito através da segunda maneira de fazer o código. Ou seja, através do uso da biblioteca matemática. O número da variável dígito aparece o número de caracteres da palavra potência, ou seja, aparece com o resultado 8.

Answer (score 2):

A saída está completamente correta.

Veja o exemplo

```
import math
res = math.pow(2, 8) # Saída: 256.0
len(str(res)) # Saída: 5
```

Isso porque ao converter a variável `res` (que é do tipo `float`) para `string` também são levados em consideração o ponto flutuante e a casa decimal.

Se você deseja ignorar as casas decimais caso o número for inteiro pode fazer a verificação usando a função `is_integer()`.

Exemplo:

```
import math

def teste(base, exp):
    res = math.pow(base, exp)
    digitos = 0    

    if(res.is_integer()):
        digitos = len(str(int(res)))
    else:
        digitos = len(str(res))

    print('resultado: %s \t digitos: %s' % (res, digitos))

teste(2, 8)      #resultado: 256.0         digitos: 3
teste(1.5, 8)    #resultado: 25.62890625   digitos: 11
teste(3.0, 8)    #resultado: 6561.0        digitos: 4
```